# Tor browser keeps failing to establish a connection

Tags: error, connection, startup

Im trying to connect to Tor, but everytime i open Tor Browser it says Tor has failed to establish a connection.
Here is the log, can anyone help me?

```
6/9/19, 21:27:32.920 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
6/9/19, 21:27:32.920 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
6/9/19, 21:27:32.920 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
6/9/19, 21:27:32.920 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
6/9/19, 21:27:32.921 [NOTICE] Opened Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
6/9/19, 21:27:32.921 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
6/9/19, 21:27:32.959 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
6/9/19, 21:30:48.972 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
6/9/19, 21:30:49.497 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
6/9/19, 21:30:51.100 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
6/9/19, 21:30:57.752 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We have no usable consensus. 
6/9/19, 21:32:07.753 [NOTICE] No circuits are opened. Relaxed timeout for circuit 8 (a General-purpose client 1-hop circuit in state doing handshakes with channel state open) to 60000ms. However, it appears the circuit has timed out anyway. 
6/9/19, 21:43:28.120 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 40%: Loading authority key certs 
6/9/19, 21:43:31.956 [NOTICE] The current consensus has no exit nodes. Tor can only build internal paths, such as paths to onion services. 
6/9/19, 21:43:31.957 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths 
6/9/19, 21:43:31.959 [NOTICE] I learned some more directory information, but not enough to build a circuit: We need more microdescriptors: we have 0/6637, and can only build 0% of likely paths. (We have 0% of guards bw, 0% of midpoint bw, and 0% of end bw (no exits in consensus, using mid) = 0% of path bw.) 
6/9/19, 21:49:13.250 [NOTICE] We'd like to launch a circuit to handle a connection, but we already have 32 general-purpose client circuits pending. Waiting until some finish. 
6/9/19, 21:49:53.969 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 10; recommendation warn; host 846B3EAAF0C07FF72FC79AEBB11FA3ADC58F240F at 62.141.48.177:443) 
6/9/19, 21:49:53.970 [WARN] 10 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:53.970 [WARN]  10 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.300 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 11; recommendation warn; host F0FE19E02AC73368380E5613D25EE4C1F7FE8872 at 178.32.223.22:443) 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.400 [WARN] 11 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.600 [WARN]  11 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.900 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 12; recommendation warn; host 0935BA9178F9E3B50C99DD53F723865FC224CFA8 at 192.124.250.83:9001) 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.900 [WARN] 12 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.100 [WARN]  12 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.130 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 13; recommendation warn; host EE010EF80A27AC0B02CDC2B8B214A6201BB02D2B at 144.76.175.205:443) 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.130 [WARN] 13 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.140 [WARN]  13 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.160 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 14; recommendation warn; host 8CAA470B905758742203E3EB45941719FCA9FEEC at 188.138.102.98:443) 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.170 [WARN] 14 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.170 [WARN]  14 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.190 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 15; recommendation warn; host F256E107631C165A22CDE1098F782D0697FA4E4F at 193.37.59.153:43597) 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.190 [WARN] 15 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.200 [WARN]  15 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.210 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 16; recommendation warn; host CE1E461FB8F5ED3FDA45A4D952E4D2440ECE1CFF at 51.38.99.152:9001) 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.210 [WARN] 16 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.220 [WARN]  16 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.240 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 17; recommendation warn; host DB131E7C4CD8807373B95EA2A5C8CF5A2269244E at 51.15.89.36:9100) 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.250 [WARN] 17 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.250 [WARN]  17 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.270 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 18; recommendation warn; host 32BA1BB34F3D6277DA0810BCB7F0D67608DE946C at 78.129.150.54:9001) 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.270 [WARN] 18 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.280 [WARN]  18 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.310 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 19; recommendation warn; host 42B4F52C5B11E4D39855F654955425B0D5A0598B at 5.9.121.207:443) 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.310 [WARN] 19 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.320 [WARN]  19 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.330 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 20; recommendation warn; host CE3FE883C6C9EF475EA097DC3E33A6F32B852DA1 at 78.129.218.56:443) 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.340 [WARN] 20 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.340 [WARN]  20 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.360 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 21; recommendation warn; host 1A8B577D27A7508A3378D1C7A63FFD4759A08C62 at 158.69.212.100:9001) 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.370 [WARN] 21 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.370 [WARN]  21 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.380 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.390 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.390 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 22; recommendation warn; host F23AC60CED6B33946B45CC22064078CB6CD980D6 at 54.37.73.76:443) 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.400 [WARN] 22 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.400 [WARN]  22 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.410 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 23; recommendation warn; host 7DDD0086A2A1D03646FCDD780C2847801459599F at 95.183.24.86:9001) 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.420 [WARN] 23 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.420 [WARN]  23 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.430 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 24; recommendation warn; host 2A3995D7A7ADA7DBD9BF5792BB156AB2A49BB2BA at 77.37.238.189:9001) 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.440 [WARN] 24 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.450 [WARN]  24 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.460 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 25; recommendation warn; host B0553175AADB0501E5A61FC61CEA3970BE130FF2 at 5.9.147.226:9001) 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.460 [WARN] 25 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.460 [WARN]  25 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.480 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 26; recommendation warn; host 12D552E8AF7AA2B71B218B5BBF6A5FEFA6F26BA0 at 217.182.196.67:443) 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.480 [WARN] 26 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.480 [WARN]  26 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.490 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 27; recommendation warn; host E09FFE941E288EA8809F6CD40D9AD1BD3BAB9EAA at 95.154.221.121:9001) 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.500 [WARN] 27 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.500 [WARN]  27 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.510 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 28; recommendation warn; host F1E6676A0551B4D88262536FAAB488B861AACA1A at 46.38.253.161:443) 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.520 [WARN] 28 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.520 [WARN]  28 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.540 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 29; recommendation warn; host 42E0FB190D20522C6C8C71E42B71DA33AC7A780E at 176.9.197.4:443) 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.540 [WARN] 29 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.540 [WARN]  29 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.560 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 30; recommendation warn; host F01B0C11CAB9B58E395874D851E879F76BC7414B at 51.15.89.36:9000) 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.560 [WARN] 30 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.570 [WARN]  30 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.580 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 31; recommendation warn; host E61CA793FDC9DAB0DA69B6235C8498E0166DEDF4 at 95.154.221.2:9001) 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.580 [WARN] 31 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.580 [WARN]  31 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.600 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 32; recommendation warn; host 3DEDA4907787B7702763BC567D01D1F430894B25 at 84.245.8.40:9001) 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.600 [WARN] 32 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.600 [WARN]  32 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.610 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 33; recommendation warn; host 15953F0C52F1A9E5CA6988A195DBA57351CC64BC at 62.210.36.177:9001) 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.620 [WARN] 33 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.620 [WARN]  33 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.630 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 34; recommendation warn; host 88748052843CC93A02BE1D9E9B5B358AB3A104AA at 178.254.40.158:443) 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.640 [WARN] 34 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.640 [WARN]  34 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.650 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 35; recommendation warn; host 6B062B0FDFEAC3C6F9203FB9584451E295574DAD at 51.15.37.97:9001) 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.660 [WARN] 35 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.660 [WARN]  35 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.670 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 36; recommendation warn; host 715A4343E852BD3856BD35176875D6A0A78DC729 at 93.90.205.104:9001) 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.670 [WARN] 36 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.680 [WARN]  36 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.690 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 37; recommendation warn; host 24F97F98C45E4754655BE66799049763DAEE99CE at 136.243.4.139:8008) 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.690 [WARN] 37 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.700 [WARN]  37 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.710 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 38; recommendation warn; host E300B83E2CD8BD2B439B47B01F9836B7BFA62C97 at 163.172.211.112:443) 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.710 [WARN] 38 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.720 [WARN]  38 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.730 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 45%: Asking for relay descriptors for internal paths. (DONE; DONE; count 39; recommendation warn; host 9C4DAED4759AA66D0E93EB27093BD21CFE2C2271 at 130.225.254.103:443) 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.730 [WARN] 39 connections have failed: 
6/9/19, 21:49:54.740 [WARN]  39 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE
```